# What does it mean to say that "an exactly equivalent way to express Hooke's Law is by the potential energy"?

Tags: classical-mechanics

From Taylor, *Classical Mechanics*

[image]

What does that last line mean? Force and energy do not have equivalent units, so I don't understand how the author relates them. Intuitively, I can see how both the force and the potential energy *oscillate*, but other than that I'm not sure what mathematical connection there is.

Comment: They are equivalent. $U(x)=kx^2/2$ implies $F(x)=-kx$, and vice versa.

Comment: @CaveJohnson "equivalent" and "implies" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you are familiar with: $-\nabla U(x)=F(x)$.

Comment: $-U'(x)=-2kx \neq -kx$.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: Where did the $1/2$ go?